# How to unmount NFS filesystem using ansible playbooks

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am trying to unmount nfs file system using ansible. I am using the below code-

```
---
- name: first playbook
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
    path: "{{ path | mandatory }}"
  tasks:
        - name: unmount nfs
          mount:
             state: unmounted
             path: "path_of_nfs_filesystem"
          register: result
          
        - debug: 
             var=result.stdout
```

But the above code is not unmounting. The output of the result is "Variable is undefined" . I have used a separate debug task as well. I have modified the code in the question as per the latest change. Kindly suggest some changes to my code. I am very new to ansible playbooks

Comment: What is the output when you print out `result` variable? You have to add a separate debug task to print that out. Also, can you unmount the filesystem manually (`sudo umount /mount/point`)?

Comment: Thanks @Lester for your help. I have updated the question with your query in the comments. currently the output says undefined "result" variable

Comment: Yes, I can unmount it manually

Comment: I think I am missing declaring some variable. Please suggest

Comment: Are you running the play in check mode? On run mode, how does the unmount task end? Lastly, try to print `result` instead of `result.stdout`.

Comment: The unmount task ends with status ok. And I tried printing the result which was as below-
ok: [localhost] => {
      "result": {
             "changed": false,
             "dump": "0",
            "failed": false,
            "fstab": "/etc...."
            "name": "the path i want to unmount"
            "opts": "defaults"
            "passno": "0"
     }
}

Comment: @Lester,  From printing the result  and its output I believe that unmount task is not getting executed. Kidnly suggest if I am missing something in the code

Answer (score 4):

I found this as a solution to my question. I hope this will help others as well

```
- name: Unmount a mounted volume
  mount:
    path: /tmp/mnt-pnt
    state: unmounted
  register: result
  retries: 5
  delay: 60
  until: result is not failed
- debug:
  var: result
```

the retries and delay is to retry upto 5 times within wait time of 60 seconds when the mount point is busy and cannot be unmounted